# Is there a bash expansion for syslog.1 syslog when syslog.1 may not exist?

Tags: bash, expansion

I'd like to monitor syslog events every hour. I use [dategrep](https://github.com/mdom/dategrep) to get the last hour but on log rotation the last hour may span to the previous syslog.

Is there an **expansion** to achieve listing the two recent syslog files in ascending order?

```
$(ls -tr syslog* | tail -n 2)
```

The output should be

```
syslog.1 syslog # when syslog.1 exists
```

or

```
syslog # when it doesn't
```

I've tried `syslog{.1,}` but it always outputs `syslog.1`.
Thank you!

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob; ls syslog syslog.[1]`? `shopt -s extglob; ls syslog+(|.1)`?

Comment: `syslog{.1,}` should expand to `syslog.1 syslog` regardless of which files actually exist; it's a pure textual expansion, not a pattern match on existing files.

Comment: With `extglob`, `syslog?(.1)` would be a more precise match, although I admit there's probably not much concern over matching `syslog.1.1.1.1` using `+(...)`.